# Can you find Airpod Case using Find my iPhone?

Tags: airpods

My Airpods are in my ears but the case is missing. It's possible it fell out of my pocket while walking around town. Is it possible to use the Find my iPhone feature to find just the Airpod Case?

Comment: Here's my hoping that this issue can be fixed with AirTag. Or if apple updated the cases with FindMy feature inherent. I've lost the case the same way as you. So I had to cash up a replacement case because the case was never found. Fast forward some year and the next case accidentally had a full wash cycle because it was forgotten in the pocket of some trousers. So yes I really wish they fix these kind of problems too because replacements are expensive. 

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you can only find the AirPods themselves. The case itself does not support Find My iPhone. You can order a replacement case under the section “Replace a missing AirPod or case” on this page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207581.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be possible as it is the case which uploads its position to the Apple servers - the AirPods which you actually stick into your ears can only play a sound. So if you select your AirPods in Find My iPhone, the location of the case will be displayed. If you have Find My iPhone activated for your iPhone, it will also be available for your AirPods. However, otherwise they will not show up in the app and you will not be able to track their location.

You can find more detailed information here:
https://www.google.de/amp/www.iphonehacks.com/2019/03/how-find-lost-airpods-case.html/amp

Good luck finding your AirPods!

Comment: Sadly AFAICT this is incorrect. I have my Airpods but not the case. I took the airpods with me this morning (the morning after I lost the case) and they show up wherever I happen to be even though I don't have the case. And yes I've emptied my pockets and my bag in the hope it was reporting the case. I think what it really reports is the last place they connected to one of your devices (iPhone/iPad/Mac)

Comment: You are right. After some further research I found out that the article I referenced is indeed wrong. What they said there sounded logical to me, but apparently Apple has still done it differently. So as you cannot find the AirPods this way now, what @gfting said is probably the best approach. I am sorry, but you might find them by going the way you went when you lost them again and checking if they lay aside the way.